# Julia language: sub vs. slice function

Tags: arrays, function, julia

Could someone explain **in simple terms** the difference between julia's v0.4 function:

[sub](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.sub) and [slice](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.slice)   (and maybe [slicedim](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.slicedim))

Some simple example would be greatly appriciated.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that `slice` drops all dimensions "sliced" with a scalar (non-vector), while `sub` often retains them. For example:

```
julia> A = rand(3,3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.403464   0.229403  0.924686
 0.953741   0.175086  0.49139 
 0.0290678  0.705564  0.567355

julia> a = slice(A, 2, :)   # this will be 1-dimensional
3-element SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},(Int64,Colon),2}:
 0.953741
 0.175086
 0.49139 

julia> b = sub(A, 2, :)     # this will be 2-dimensional
1x3 SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},(UnitRange{Int64},Colon),2}:
 0.953741  0.175086  0.49139

julia> size(a)
(3,)

julia> size(b)
(1,3)
```

There's one exception: `sub` drops dimensions indexed with a scalar *if* they are "trailing" dimensions, meaning there are no later dimensions indexed with a vector:

```
julia> a = slice(A, :, 2)
3-element SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},(Colon,Int64),2}:
 0.229403
 0.175086
 0.705564

julia> b = sub(A, :, 2)
3-element SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},(Colon,Int64),2}:
 0.229403
 0.175086
 0.705564

julia> size(a)
(3,)

julia> size(b)
(3,)
```

If you `slice` with a range, then you get behavior like `sub`:

```
julia> a = slice(A, 2:2, :)
1x3 SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},(UnitRange{Int64},Colon),1}:
 0.953741  0.175086  0.49139

julia> size(a)
(1,3)
```

It's not the length of the index that matters, it's the type: any dimension indexed with a non-scalar will be retained.

Comment: **If you slice with a range, then you get behavior like sub**. Are there any additional functionality with `sub` which can not be done with `slice`. Or could `slice` replace `sub` in every circumstances.