# Extract rows / columns of a matrix into separate variables

Tags: julia

The following question came up in my course yesterday:

Suppose I have a matrix `M = rand(3, 10)` that comes out of a calculation, e.g. an ODE solver.

In Python, you can do

`x, y, z = M`

to extract the rows of `M` into the three variables, e.g. for plotting with `matplotlib`.

In Julia we could do

```
M = M'  # transpose 
x = M[:, 1]
y = M[:, 2]
z = M[:, 3]
```

Is there a nicer way to do this extraction?
It would be nice to be able to write at least (approaching Python)

```
x, y, z = columns(M)
```

or

```
x, y, z = rows(M)
```

One way would be

```
columns(M) = [ M[:,i] for i in 1:size(M, 2) ]
```

but this will make an expensive copy of all the data.

To avoid this would we need a new iterator type, `ColumnIterator`, that returns slices? Would this be useful for anything other than using this nice syntax?

Comment: Why not `columns(M) = [ slice(M,:,i) for i in 1:size(M, 2) ]`? What is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Without copying: columns(M) = [sub(M,:,i) for i in 1:size(M, 2)]

Comment: Yes, that should work, thanks! -- not sure why I didn't think of it.

Comment: Apparently `slice` and `sub` do the same thing in this case; both return a view (not a copy).

Comment: Sorry, they both return a view, but `sub` returns a 2D matrix, whereas `slice` suppresses the singleton index and returns a vector, which is what e.g. PyPlot needs.

Comment: You decide what you need. The differences are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185183/julia-language-sub-vs-slice-function

Answer (score 1):

`columns(M) = [ slice(M,:,i) for i in 1:size(M, 2) ]`

and

`columns(M) = [ sub(M,:,i) for i in 1:size(M, 2) ]`

They both return a view, but slice drops all dimensions indexed with
scalars.

Answer (score 1):

A nice alternative that I have just found if `M` is a `Vector` of `Vector`s (instead of a matrix) is using `zip`:

```
julia> M = Vector{Int}[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]

julia> a, b, c = zip(M...)
Base.Zip2{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}}([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

julia> a, b, c
((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))
```